# Find any asymptotes for $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus

Find any asymptotes for the function $f(x)$.

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}$$

I don't even know how to start. Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Notice that when $x\rightarrow -1$, $f(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ and $x\rightarrow 1$, $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: For large $x$ $f(x) \sim x^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for any point at which the function is undefined, in this case (asymptote can mean many more things as you get more familiar).  So, when is the denominator equal to $0$?

Comment: Okay I see, so it's quite easy to find the vertical asymptotes. But   what about oblique/slant asymptotes? How can I find them?

Comment: For those sorts of asymptotes, you look at what $f(x)$ approaches as $x\to\pm\infty$.  In this case, $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $x^{1/3}$, which does not produce such an asymptote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume that you need to adjust or simplify the function in some way in order to reach that conclusion. How is that done?

Comment: As $x\to\pm\infty$, $x^2-1=x^2$, so $\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}=x^{1/3}$

Comment: This was very helpful. There just one thing I don't really understand. Maybe it's hard for you to answer, but how do you know when your'e done simplifying the expression? Is it because we can confirm that when x→±∞, the function(x^(1/3))also →±∞?

Comment: Well, that's part of it, I suppose, but you'd know if the function tended to a finite value.  In this case you know you're done because you can't really simplify $x^{1/3}$; it's a really clean expression as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{x{^{2}}-1}=0|(){^{3}}|+1$$

$$ x{^{2}}=1|\sqrt[]{}$$
$$x_{1}=1 , x_{2}=-1$$

Comment: How can I find oblique/slant asymptotes?